# How to work with git using a bare repository?

Tags: git, teamcity

I'm having problems working with a bare git repository.

It seems like our build server, TeamCity, creates bare repositories when cloning the original repository and I want to do a manual update of the submodules.

I've experimented with the following:

## Create repo 1

```
cd c:\temp
mkdir g1
cd g1
git init
echo lala > ape.txt
git add *
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

## Clone to bare repo 2

```
cd c:\temp
git clone --bare g1 g2
```

## Create a new directory with the same content as g1

```
mkdir test
cd test
echo lala > ape.txt
git --git-dir=..\g2 --work-tree=. status

# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    ape.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       ape.txt
```

Why doesn't git recognize that the ape.txt file is already in the repository?

What I in the end want to accomplish is something like this

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/bare/repo --work-tree=/path/to/checkoutdir submodule init
git --git-dir=/path/to/bare/repo --work-tree=/path/to/checkoutdir submodule ??? <= to clone one specific submodule of several in the repository
```